# Solvability of an integral equation

Tags: operator-theory, integral-operators

Is it possible to find $f,g\in L^2[(0,1)\times(0,1)]$ such that $$\log|x-y|=\int_0^1f(x,t)g(t,y)dt\:\:\:\forall x,y\in(0,1).$$

Comment: The LHS isn't defined for ALL $x,y\in (0,1)$. Moreover, by Fubini + Cauchy-Schwarz, for a.e. $a$, the RHS will give a finite answer for $x=y=a$.

Comment: The function $L(x,y)=\log|x-y|$ is defined a.e in $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I'm elaborating on my comment: By CS, it would follow that $\left|\ln |x-y|\right| \le A(x)B(y)$, with $A,B\in L^2(0,1)$. So $\left| \ln |x-y|\right| \le C A(x)$ for a.e. $x$ and all $y$ from a set of almost full measure.

Comment: Thanks. In fact your proof simplifies a fact related to certain operator.